# Ubuntu 19.10 - How to set local DNS IP for local wifi connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, systemd, systemd-resolved

I recently purchased a raspberry pi and got pi-hole running on it. Unfortunately, my router does not allow me to use the raspberry pi as the network-wide DNS server so I want my laptop (Ubuntu 19.10) to use the raspberry pi/pi-hole as a custom DNS server.

The first thing I tried is: settings menu --> wifi settings --> home wifi connection --> add the static IP of my raspberry pi

[Local DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeFeb.png)

When I run `resolvectl status` my DNS entry is listed under "DNS Servers" but "Current DNS" is set to a Comcast server (I have xfinity at home) and my pi IP is ignored. If I repeat the same process but instead use Cloudflare's `1.1.1.1` or `1.0.0.1`, then `resolvectl status` displays the expected "Current DNS" as the Cloudflare DNS. If I add both the raspberry pi and the Cloudflare IPs like `10.0.0.XXX, 1.1.1.1`, `resolvectl status` shows "Current DNS" set to the Cloudflare IP (pi IP is again ignored).

So my question is: why is my local pi IP being ignored?

Also, fwiw, I tested the pi IP using a macbook and confirmed that pihole is working. I also manually edited `/etc/resolv.conf` with my raspberry pi IP and confirmed this worked. I was also able to set the current DNS manually with `sudo resolvectl dns wlp2s0 10.0.0.X` but this change doesn't stick after reboot.

Also, for my own education, which networking and resolving services run by default on Ubuntu 19.10? I have seen people mention: `systemd-networkd`, `netplan`, and `network-manager` on various forums. Similarly, how can I tell which DNS service is running? I have seen people mentioned `systemd-resolved`, `resolvconf`, and `dnsmasq`.

Thanks!